# Fluorescence Correlation Spectroscopy Simulation

Tags: list-manipulation, random, simulation

I am simulating Fluorescence Correlation Spectroscopy which basically involves tracking the random motion of particles in a box with periodic boundary conditions and then calculating their intensity using a 3D Gaussian function where the particles are at their maximum intensity at the center of the box.  Finally, the intensities of the particles are then summed up for each time step.  The problem I am having is manipulating a very large list of lists when calculating the intensity of each particle at each time step.

```
Timing[Clear["Global`*"]
  ClearSystemCache[];
 n = 10.;
 radius = 5.*10.^-9.;
 k = 1.38*10.^-23.;
 T = 293.;
 Eta = 1.*10.^-3.;
 d = (k*T)/(6.*\[Pi]*Eta*radius);
 Deltat = 500000.;
 time = 10.*10.^-6.;
 Taud = (Omegar^2./(4.*d));
 Omegar = 200.*10.^-9.;
 Omegaz = 5.*Omegar;
 Io = 1;
 boundary = 5.*10.^-6.;
 initial = boundary/2.;
 step = Sqrt[2.*d*time];
 RandomWalk[x_] := 
  Accumulate[
   Join[{RandomReal[{-initial, initial}, 3]}, 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, step], {x, 3}]]];
 p = Table[
   Mod[RandomWalk[Deltat], boundary, -initial], {i, n}];
 particleintensity = 
  Table[Io*Exp[(-2.*(p[[i, t, 1]]^2. + p[[i, t, 2]]^2.))/Omegar^2. - (2. (p[[i, t, 
  3]]^2.))/Omegaz^2.], {t, 1, Deltat + 1}, {i, n}];
int = Total[particleintensity, {2}];
ListPlot[int, AxesOrigin -> {0., 0.}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "I"}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotStyle -> Red]]

{87.2093,"Plot"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the example above, I have 10 particles for 500,000 time steps and it takes a considerable amount of time.  The majority of the calculation time occurs at the end when calculating the variable `particleintensity`.  I am thinking that there has to be a faster way to do this that utilizes less memory.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question per se ... but ... if you are doing work on Fluorescence Fluctuation Spectroscopy, you might be interested in a paper that uses *Mathematica* and mathStatica to analyse this topic by: Muller, Joachim D. (2004), Cumulant Analysis in Fluorescence Fluctuation Spectroscopy, *Biophysical Journal*, Volume 86, 3981–3992

Comment: What happens if you use `particleintensity = Io*Exp[-2 Table[With[{v = p[[i, t]]}, Norm[Take[v, 2]]^2/Omegar^2 + (Last[v]^2)/Omegaz^2], {t, Deltat + 1}, {i, n}]]`?

Comment: @J.M.  It is actually about 10% slower for me.

Comment: @Kane, have you tried to compile the Table?

Comment: @Kane this is rather interesting. Is this molecular dynamics?

Comment: @drN In a sense, yes this is molecular dynamics.  Once I have an total intensity profile I can autocorrelate it and extract information such as concentration and diffusion coefficients among many other things.

Comment: @ruebenko No, I haven't attempted to compile it.  My programming skills are still rather basic.  I'm not quite sure how to use Compile yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to iterate over `i` and `t` to build `particleintensity`, just do the whole dot product in one go. The `Exp` moves outside the dot product (so we use it once as a `Listable` function rather than 5 million times individually).

```
particleintensity = Io Exp[(p^2).{-2/Omegar^2, -2/Omegar^2, -2/Omegaz^2}];    
int = Total[particleintensity];
```

This runs about 250 times faster than the original `Table` version.

**Update**

Since the final result `int` is obtained by summing over `n`, there is no need to hold all the data in memory at once. The $n$ elements of `p` and `particleintensity` can be computed sequentially, accumulating the values of `particleintensity` at each step. This will result in lower memory usage:

```
int = 0;
Do[
 p = Mod[RandomWalk[Deltat], boundary, -initial];
 particleintensity = Io Exp[(p^2).{-2/Omegar^2, -2/Omegar^2, -2/Omegaz^2}];
 int += particleintensity,
 {n}]
```

Comment: This has been working great.  However, I have found that I need Deltat to be at least 1000000 and n to be at least 50.  Using these parameters, the calculation of particle intensity still takes a considerable amount of time.  Realistically, I only need to calculate the particle intensity when particles are close to the origin, say within a distance of Omegaz or Omegar.  If I could only calculate particle intensity when particles are close to the origin, I think that would seriously reduce my calculation time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kane, for me the slowest part of the calculation now is the generation of the random numbers. Are you still finding the computation of `particleintensity` to be the bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, when i set n to 50 and Deltat to 10^6 'particleintensity' is the slowest bit.  However, this is not the case when n is set to 5 and Deltat is 10^6.  I need a way to only calculate particle intensity for particles that are close to the origin.

Comment: @Kane, with `n=50` and `Deltat=10^6` I get timings of 13s for calculating `p` and 2.5s for calculating `particleintensity`, so I can't reproduce your problem. It could be memory related - I'll post an edit with lower memory usage.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that it is a memory issue.  I am working with 4GB of memory and a 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to double the speed by simply moving some multiplications and divisions...

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  or2 = -2./Omegar^2.;
  oz2 = 2./Omegaz^2.;
  p = p^2.;
  Io*Table[
           Exp[(p[[i, t, 1]] + p[[i, t, 2]])*or2 - p[[i, t, 3]]*oz2],
           {t, 1, Deltat + 1}, {i, n}];
]
```

A dot product is 30 to 40% faster still.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  or2 = -2./Omegar^2.;
  oz2 = 2./Omegaz^2.;
  v = {or2, or2, -oz2};
  p = p^2.;
  Io*Table[Exp[p[[i, t]].v],{t,1,Deltat+1},{i,n}];
]
```

Comment: This is about 50% faster for me too.  Thanks.

Comment: That's even better!  Thanks.